# Something is wrong with comments

Tags: bug, comments

[image]

The comments on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-many-consecutive-positive-integers-can-you-make-using-exactly-four-instances) don't appear to be correctly wrapping.

I'm using Safari 9.0.3 on OSX 10.11.3.

I'm not sure if this has been reported yet or not.  Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Reproduced using IE 7; it goes away on Chrome but I see some weird MathJax stuff going on.

Comment: repro with Chrome 48 on Windows after opening them up. Seems to be independent of resolution

Comment: Indeed.  I was thinking it might be some MathJax issue.  If we guess at MathJax, we can probably reproduce on this question.

Comment: I think the culprit is [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-many-consecutive-positive-integers-can-you-make-using-exactly-four-instances#comment82976_27983) with it's huge chain of `sec arctan` which seems to not properly wrap, because it's not marked as text...

Comment: Strangely enough this didn't seem to be an issue with Chrome 48 on OSX 10.10.5, **before** I expand "show more comments". Then it appears here as well

Comment: This is also being discussed on [Puzzling Meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4579/16077).